# How to trim/cut clips with VLC

Tags: macos, vlc-media-player

I am running VLC 1.1.5 64-bit on Mac OS X 10.6.6. On the web I found instructions saying I should click on Video->Advanced Controls in the menu bar to reveal options that let me trim and cut video clips. However, there is no such option in my copy of VLC.

What I want to do is cut a ~2 minute portion from the middle of a two hour footage (in MXF format that QuickTime can't open) that I've got.

Is there another way to trim and cut clips of videos in VLC? Or should I use other (preferably free, Free, and open source) software? Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For some reason VLC has removed options to stream a partial clip from their transcoding and streaming wizards. But the options are still available at the cli.

Here's how I stream a portion of a file, while keeping the original audio and video streams intact (no transcoding done). Times are given in seconds:

> vlc in.avi --start-time 65 --stop-time 95 :sout=#file{dst=/home/myser/Desktop/out.avi} :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :sout-keep

With transcoding:

> vlc in.avi --start-time 65 --stop-time 158 :sout='#transcode{vcodec=mp2v,vb=4096,acodec=mp2a,ab=192,scale=1,channels=2,deinterlace,audio-sync}:std{access=file, mux=ps,dst=/home/myser/Desktop/out.mpg}'

More info on transcoding [here](http://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode).

Comment: Since vlc is probably not on your PATH in OSX, you must call it from its app bundle like
`/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC`
or set an alias (temporary or in your .bashrc) like
`alias vlc="/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC"`

Comment: ... but that doesn’t help, since you need some CLI version "cvlc", that I couldn’t find. :(

Comment: Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface, and if you update .bashrc by vlc="/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC", use source ~/.bashrc to force reload after your modification.

Answer (score 49):

Yes, Using VLC player on mac to cut a part of the video is possible..

Goto

"Playback" in top menu while playing the video and at the point where u want to start cropping, click on

"Record", the tick mark beside Record in the sub menu indicates that the recording is happening, click again when u have to stop the cropping.

**OPTION + COMMAND + R to start cropping

OPTION + COMMAND + R again to stop cropping**

the cropped video saves to home directory by default in mp4 format

Comment: This works on a Mac, but only if you first go into your Preferences and choose what the default folder is for any recorded files.

Comment: In order to set the recorded file's location, go to Preferences > Input / Codecs / Record directory or filename. I also had to restart VLC to make it work.

Comment: For me the default was ~/Music (home music folder)

Comment: BUT it produces stucky video and we have to wait for the recording. So it is not technically "cut the video"

Comment: I'm on El Capitan 10.11.1 with VLC 2.0.4 and my default directory was `~/Movies`.

Comment: Works - sort of - as I don't get audio on the recorded clip...

Comment: how to trim the video in one shot? (without having to read the whole video)

Comment: This records only sound (.wav), any idea why?

Answer (score 18):

If you're up for other software, just try QuickTime, it has very nice and easy trim controls, you just drag the sliders at the video progress bar and then there's a trim option (I believe it's Cmd+T).

Comment: Unfortunately it is an MXF file and QuickTime can't open it (I will edit my question to reflect that), any other ideas?

Comment: If you were on Windows, I'd suggest VirtualDub, but I haven't come across MXFs yet..